# Gas Furnace Creaks When The Wind Blows

Tags: hvac, furnace

I have a Williams Forsaire Top Vent‎ gas furnace that creaks when a strong gust of wind blows. Could the venting be loose or not fitting right? Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where does the creaking sound come from?

Comment: It sounds like its coming from the top of the heater around where the heater connects to the vent. Its a new heater but the vents are old. Also on a windy or snowy day the heater completely shuts off after a minute. I'm guessing its a venting issue and they need to be replaced.